# Improving THREE js loading time

Tags: performance, three.js

I'm new to webgl and three js but I managed to finished a small project in a few weeks. But what I want to ask is, what can I do do improve loading times of the app? I'm not complaining about the fps's because the interaction with it is smooth, but it takes quite a while to load everything. Do you guys have any tips or resources that I can check to improve the bundle js loading times?

Im using d3, topojson and three js. The project is a 3d globe with a background image. The globe has a texture and it shows the overlay of the country you're hovering with (so it has mousemove and click events). It also has 3d markers (spheres and cylinders) and interact when you click them.

I tried removing all the code i could, avoid heavy computations, and use BufferGeometry everywhere I could. It also has particles. Since it uses click events I needed Projector.js and I needed OrbitControls.js for the controls logic. Im using debounce on the events also. I'm just asking about general three js tips, some guidelines to avoid waiting 6-9seconds for whole scene to load. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very broad question, and you have provided very few details. How much data are you loading? What format? How much overhead is there beyond the three.js side of things? What have you done to try to make it better?

Comment: you're right. gonna edit my question

Comment: I think your question is still overly-broad. Asking for "general tips and tricks" isn't an answerable question ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). That said, start by profiling the loading process. I'm willing to bet a majority of the time is spent in the topojson loader (wherever that lives). Once you've narrowed it down, and have taken some steps to improve the situation yourself, narrow-down your question so we can help with a _specific_ problem you're encountering.

Comment: ^ +1, start by using your browser's profiling tools to figure out what's taking so long. Downloading resources? The first render frame? Once you have that, and if you're not sure how to improve them, that's a more answerable question.

Comment: You might find [this useful](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference)

Comment: thank you guys. Sorry for the broad question :/ I had nowhere to look lol. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- shrink your 3D model data;
- use compressed texture format such as dds or crunch;
- cut big scene into small ones and load them by lods;

Hope this helpful.